# How to get source system from properties file?

Tags: java

I am trying to get source system from properties file below into source_system_1 array. How to accomplish this without using `org.ini4j.Ini` library and instead using `java.util.Properties`?

This is my `fileProcessing.ini`:

```ini
sourceSystem=ABC
sourceSystem=XYZ
sourceSystem=FGH
sourceSystem=RTY
```

This is my code

```java
Properties fileProp = new Properties();
fileProp.load(new FileInputStream("fileProcessing.ini"));

String[] source_system_1 = {"ABC", "XYZ", "FGH", "RTY"};

String source_system_string = fileProp.getProperty("sourceSystemMUB");
String[] source_system_array = source_system_string.split("\\s+");
List<String> source_system_list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(source_system_array));
source_system_list.removeAll(Collections.singleton(""));
String[] source_system_1 = source_system_list.toArray(new String[0]);
```

I am not getting in the expected array `{"ABC", "XYZ", "FGH", "RTY"}` with all values of `sourceSystem`.

Comment: Why do you want to use the `java.util.Properties` class? Why do you not want to use a different library or your own class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read the property file when duplicate key-value pair exist in the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511865/how-to-read-the-property-file-when-duplicate-key-value-pair-exist-in-the-file)

Comment: You can simply append an index to each duplicated key and then retrieve them all sequentially until you get a null